# QtWebkit, Can't use '@' key

Tags: qt, webview, webkit, qt5, qtwebkit

My Qt program (using qt v5.0.2) contains a QWebView in which the user is supposed to login using their email address and a password.
Everything works fine on Windows (tried on w7 and server 2008) but on Mac (10.7.5) I have encountered an annoying issue.
When pressing alt-2 (key combination for @) nothing happens.

I have spent countless hours testing and trying to find any info on the net about it, but I really can't find anything about it.

Is there any workaround? Fix? Or is this even a known issue?

Edit:
As noted in comments below, my keyboard is European/Swedish.

Comment: alt-2 ? shouldn't it be shift-2 ?

Comment: Ramez, Swedish/European keyboard, so alt+2, shift+2 is ".
This might be a good thing to add to the first post now when I think about it, cause I guess this might have something to do with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a genuine Qt Bug. I reported it as  https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-34981

Today we found the code responsible for it in

```
./qtwebkit/Source/WebKit/qt/WebCoreSupport/EditorClientQt.cpp
```

Around line 480 it says

```
#ifndef Q_WS_MAC
    // We need to exclude checking for Alt because it is just a different Shift                                                            
     if (!kevent->altKey())
#endif
     shouldInsertText = true;
```

Apparently, Q_WS_MAC isn't defined on Mac Builds at this time - I think it's been deprecated in favor of Q_OS_MAC.S

Simply changing the statement to

```
shouldInsertText = true;
```

when compiling on Mac fixed the problem for us.

Comment: I'm very happy to hear this and will try it out as soon as I get to my work tomorrow. The project is closed and we managed to hack around it, but I'm glad that its found, cause it was a pain! hehe.
I'll mark the answer as correct as soon as I have tested and if it works!